# Enter Password through bourne shell script when asked by the command without expect

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a bourne shell script for the openwrt firware where I want to copy my files from router to linux machine. when i do

```
scp /etc/clients.txt shah@192.168.1.2:/home/shah/
```

from inside the router's openwrt firmware, it asks me to give the password. I want to give this password from within the script because this file needs to be copied after every 2 seconds. How can I do this without using expect?

Comment: You can configure scp for passwordless login. See http://www.phcomp.co.uk/Tutorials/Unix-And-Linux/ssh-passwordless-login.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`sshpass`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/) tool but you will need to provide a password in clear text in your script. If that is not a problem you should use it.

```
sshpass -p 'password'  scp /etc/clients.txt shah@192.168.1.2:/home/shah/
```

Comment: I used this code but their is another requirement that i want to save the output to a file and send it over to the linux client, but this command does not send anything into the file i specify using `> file.txt` or `2>&1 | tee file.txt`. So i skipped this option

Comment: -v with sshpass? as in to save the output to my file?

Comment: usual "-v" says verbose - this means that you should see the output.
try to run this  sshpass -v and sshpass -p "password" scp -v command without saving to file and see in which case you see the ouput. After you will see the output - try to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: i tried to get the list of mac addresses connected to my router with this command `iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep Station | cut -f 2 -s -d" " 2>&1 |tee clients.txt` written in a script in linux. This works but now i need to get this file back on my computer which requires scp and asks for password, but i want this process to be seamless once i code it i.e. i dont want to enter password each time i run the script. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you please be more clearly and provide the exact steps? 
In your question you copy the file FROM your pc to remote pc

Comment: Okay here is the detail:

Comment: I don't see. But lets try to underrstand how do you make it manual an I will write a script.
1. You enter to a router with some username and password.
2. You run some command you see some output.
3. you want to save this output to some file.
Is those steps are correct?

Comment: Okay here is the detail:
1. i wrote a script as :
`#!/bin/sh
iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep Station | cut -f 2 -s -d" " 2>&1 | tee /etc/clients.txt`
this script runs onto my router.
2. Then i want to send this file to my PC with ip 192.168.1.2 and name:shah. 
3. I used two different approaches. First I tried to run command from PC to router and get the output on my PC using > command as already stated. But this does not give me any output. Then i wrote the script above on router and saved its output to clients.txt within the router and im trying to send this file to my linux machine

Comment: Step2 command:
 Then i want to send this file to my PC with ip 192.168.1.2 and name:shah. with this command 
`scp /etc/clients.txt shah@192.168.1.2:/home/shah/`. Here it asks me to give password for my PC. But i want this to be automatic.

Comment: Dont you think is very complex for this sipmle goal?

Just make a sctipt that will connect your router -> run a commnd -> save output to a file.

The script should be like this:

sshpass -p user@IPOFROUTER COMMAND > /tmp/clients.txt


If you still want go by your way - run sshpass -p scp user@router://path_to_a_file     /tmp/clients.txt

Comment: that's exactly what i did, but it does not output anything to my file. Its blank all the time

Comment: if you run a command 

sshpass -p "password" root@192.168.x.7 command 



Do you see some output?

Comment: no their is no output, but when i run the command itself after telneting into the router, i get a list of connected macs

Comment: Very strange... Are you working with general terminal of linux ubuntu/centos?

Comment: which router is this ? which command do you use to get output of connected clients?

Comment: i use this command iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep Station | cut -f 2 -s -d" " 2>&1 | tee /etc/clients.txt from linux, and my router is tplink tl-WR740n with openwrt firmware

Comment: OK, and by running this command do you get the client file as you need?

What happnend when you run the command: 


sshpass -p "password" scp roo@router://etc/client.txt   /tmp/localclientfile.txt ON YOUR LINUX macine ?

Comment: NO, i don't get any output. But when i run the command  iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep Station | cut -f 2 -s -d" " 2>&1 | tee /etc/clients.txt from inside the router,it outputs the list of clients in the file. There is some issue with sshpass command i suppose but it does not give any errors apparently

Comment: I am asking about two different steps.. Do you want provide me teamviwer and we will take a look together?

Comment: i dont have a teamviewer. Ok i ran the command again , the one just said  `sshpass -p "password" scp root@router://etc/client.txt /tmp/localclientfile.txt` and it returned `Host key verification Failed` . I opened another terminal and ssh into the router, but their is no conflict with that, i successfully logged in

Comment: it is free - you can install it.

DO you have crontab on the router?

Comment: can you run command:

"""sshpass -p 'password' iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep Station > /tmp/clients.txt""" as I wrote it and let me know if you get some output in /tmp/client.txt?

Comment: in linux it gives error now "command failed no such device (-19)", however wlan0 is enbled and i again ran the command in router and it gave a mac address in its output

Comment: in the command u asked me to run i added ssh root@192.168.1.1 after password, and it dint give any errors or output

Comment: Sorry man - I need to see with my ayes step by step in order to help you.
If you really need it - install any remote access application and we will try to understand what is going on.

Comment: here is my team viewer id 329 200 398. contact me on this please

Comment: send me the temporary password to maxpal.mail@gmail.com

Comment: FOr others having such problem ,let me tell u the problem in my case. I had problem with permanently adding the root user to RSA list with error giving as "Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts". I'll open up a new case for that.